# Marshalling an active object with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, active-objects

I am trying to marshal a class which extends Thread to XML, the code is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TransitionXML extends Thread {

ArcXML[] preArcs;
ArcXML[] postArcs;
int[] preArcTokens;
int[] postArcTokens;
int leastTime;
int longestTime;
String name;

//some methods 

//a lot of get-set

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (this.postTransition() & this.preTransition()) {
            //We take out the tokens.
            this.executePreTranstion();
            this.checkPreTransition();


            try {
                this.sleep(1000 * this.getTimeToPass());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TransitionXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //We see if we can put them in.
            if (this.postTransition()) {
                this.executePostTranstion();
                this.checkPostTransition();
            }

        } else {
            try {
                this.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TransitionXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}


}

public TransitionXML()
{

}

}
```

}

Which leads me to this error: `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces. ... java.lang.Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler does not have a no-arg default constructor.`

If I understood this correctly the very fact that it extends Thread causes this problem but I haven't seen a solution on the net.

Does anyone know of a solution or work-around for this, besides making the class a object which implements runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you use MOXy as your JAXB provider then you can use your `TransitionXML` class as is.  This is because MOXy will not attempt to create metadata for classes in a `java` or `javax` package such as `java.lang.Thread`.

You can obtain the MOXy binary from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to put a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Netbeans, is there any way to add Moxy to it, a plug-in perhaps?